# How to call coffescript file function in a js file?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have "update" function in my coffeescript file. I want to call this function from another js file when a button is clicked.(since I will use ajax call, I want to call update from a js file.)

Here is the part how I define the files in html:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="coffee/vis.coffee"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Site.js"></script>
```

This is my update functio defined in vis.coffee:

```
update = () ->
curNodesData = filterNodes(allData.nodes)
curLinksData = filterLinks(allData.links, curNodesData)
.
.
.
```

I have the following code in my js file

```
$("#popular").on("click",function(){
   update();
})
```

But it says update is not defined. How can I call this update function? Thanks for any help.

Comment: please provide the coffeescript function as well as how these 2 files are defined/loaded into the JS runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: You need to transpile your coffee code to JS in order for it to work.  I assume you're running this through the browser.  Unless you have a special plugin or something, the browser has no idea how to utilize the coffeescript. The only thing that would run coffee files straight from the browser is something like this - http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/browser.html